# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation Match with Date and average

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB java driver to query transactions between date range and average of value with aggregate framework. This is my mongo query (it works):

```
db.campaignsForChatUsers.aggregate([{$match:{'created' :
 {$gte : ISODate('2017-09-30T11:35:35.155Z'), $lt : ISODate('2019-09-30T11:35:35.155Z')}}},
{$group: {_id : "_id", aveTime: { $avg : "$details.nostradamusOfferCalculatingTime"}}}])
```

The java code I'm using to make query:

```
public Double getAverageTimeWithPeriod(){
    MongoCollection<Document> dbCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(ChatUserCampaign.COLLECTION_NAME);

    Date fromDate = LocalDate.parse("2019-10-01").toDate();
    Date toDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-03-13").toDate();

    BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
            new BasicDBObject("created",
                    new BasicDBObject("$gte", fromDate/*getDate("01/10/2019")*/).append("$lt", toDate/*getDate("20/10/2019")*/)));
    BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",
            new BasicDBObject ("_id",
                    new BsonField("averageTime",
                    new BsonDocument("$avg,",
                            new BsonString("$details.nostradamusOfferCalculatingTime")))));

    List<Bson> aggregators = null;
    assert false;

    aggregators.add(match);
    aggregators.add(group);
    AggregateIterable<Document> output = dbCollection.aggregate(aggregators);
    //AggregationOutput output1 = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match,group));
    Document result = output.first();
    return result.getDouble("averageTime");
}
```

But this jaja query is returning empty results (in line with: `aggregators.add(match);` - I get NullPointerException).

Answer (score 0):

Mongo don't understand `01/10/2019` format rather it understand ISO format. Hence, you must be using something like `ISODate("2015-06-17T10:03:46Z")` in place of `fromDate` and `toDate`. `Date` or `LocalDate` don't work.

Comment: Date is ok. This code: <code>Date fromDate = LocalDate.parse("2019-10-01").toDate();</code> working ok. So this is no problem.